# Как сделать проверку в if на наличие в EditText текста?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

```
        String [] items = new String[editArr.size()];

    for(int i=0; i < editArr.size(); i++)
    {
        if(editArr.get(i).getText().toString() != null)
        {
            items[i] = ((EditText) editArr.get(i)).getText().toString();
            Log.e("", ((EditText) editArr.get(i)).getText().toString());
        }

    }
```

Попробовал сделать так, но даже AndroidStudio говорит о том, что условие в if всегда true. Мне необходимо записывать в массив items текст и выводить это в логи только в том случае, если edittext имеет этот текст, а  если не имеет - переходить на следующий повтор цикла.
Возможно, если в edittext нет текста это не null а что-то другое?

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText());

Comment: @Эникейщик Сработало, спасибо! Можете переместить в ответы, я отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
if (editText.getText().length() == 0)
```

или так

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText()))
```